# What is causing my pointer to not update its pointed-to address and display the correct value?

Tags: c

I am trying to practice with pointers a little and cannot seem to understand where I messed up with the example below. I created two integer variables and assigned them values. I also created an integer pointer and assigned it the first integer variables address. I then try to pass a hexidecimal address using scanf() to the pointer so it updates its pointed-to address. Then I attempt to print the decimal value of the pointer which if it was working correctly should be 200 but it still shows the original address of number 1's value which is 100.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int number1 = 100;
  int number2 = 200;
  int *p = &number1;

  printf("Number 1 Value: %d \n", number1);
  printf("Number 1 Address: 0x%X \n\n", &number1);

  printf("Number 2 Value: %d \n", number2);
  printf("Number 2 Address: 0x%X \n\n", &number2);

  printf("Pointer Number 1 Value: %d \n\n", *p);

  printf("Enter Number 2's Address to view it's value: ");
  scanf("%X", *p);

  printf("\nPointer Value: %d\n\n", *p);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`scanf("%X", *p);` has three errors:

- A correct conversion specification for pointers is `%p`, not `%X`.
- The argument must be the address of the pointer, but `*p` passes the value of the pointed-to object, not the address of the pointer.
- The argument must point to a `void *`, but `p` is an `int *`.

Going back to the earlier `printf` calls, to print an address, use `%p` and convert the address to `void *`:

```
printf("Number 1 Address: 0x%p\n\n", (void *) &number1);
printf("Number 2 Address: 0x%p\n\n", (void *) &number2);
printf("Pointer Number 1 Value: 0x%p\n\n", (void *) p);
```

When a pointer is passed to `printf` as the argument for a `%X` or `%d` conversion specification, the behavior is not defined by the C standard. When `%p` is used, the argument should be a `void *`. (Passing an `int *` is insufficient to guarantee behavior defined by the C standard, so convert it to `void *`.)

To scan an address, you must supply the address of a `void *`. Because `p` is an `int *`, you cannot properly scan directly into it. Create a temporary `void *` and use it for scanning:

```
// Create temporary "void *".
void *t;

// Scan into the "void *".
int result = scanf("%p", &t);

// Check return value of scanf.
if (result != 1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, scanf did not work.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// Convert from temporary "void *" to "int *".
p = t;
```

Answer (score 2):

With `*p` in your call to `scanf()`, you pass the value to which p points, which is `100`. `scanf()` interprets `100` as the address to some place in which to store your input, which leads to a program crash on my computer.

You need to pass pointers to `scanf()`, pointing to data that `scanf()` then can modify. So you need to pass the address of (in other words, a pointer to) your variable `p` by writing `&p`, as susanth29 said.

---

As a sidenote, you should use `%p` to print pointers. If you compile your program as 64bit, addresses are going to be 64bit. But with `%X` they are being truncated to 32bit. Alternatively you could use `0x%lx` or `0x%lX`. To Illustrate, the output on my computer of the following code

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int number1 = 100;
  printf("Number 1 Address: 0x%X \n", &number1);
  printf("Number 1 Address: %p \n", &number1);
  printf("Number 1 Address: 0x%lX \n\n", &number1);
  return 0;
}
```

```
Number 1 Address: 0x96B54518 
Number 1 Address: 0x7ffd96b54518 
Number 1 Address: 0x7FFD96B54518
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `scanf("%X", *p);` to `scanf("%X", &p);`. It works though it's not the correct way.

Comment: @4386427 Maybe because it works? I am not knowledgeable about format specifiers, so can you specify what is wrong instead of just saying it's wrong.

Comment: A correct conversion specification for printing or scanning pointers is `%p`, and the argument should be a `void *` (when printing) or `void **` (when scanning). The C standard does not define the behavior when `%X` is used for a pointer or when an `int **` is passed for scanning with `%p`. To print an `int *` named `p`, one should use `printf("%p", (void *) p)`. To scan it, one should use `void *t; int result = scanf("%p", &t); /* Check result. */ p = t;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number1 = 100;
    int number2 = 200;
    int *p = &number1;

    printf("\nNumber 1 Value: %d \n", number1);
    printf("Number 1 Address: 0x%p \n\n", &number1);

    printf("\nAddress of pointer = %p\n\n", p);

    printf("Number 2 Value: %d \n", number2);
    printf("Number 2 Address: 0x%p \n\n", &number2);

    printf("\nDon't copy the initial '0x' from Number 2 address, Why? Compare the addresses of Number 1 and p above.\n");

    printf("Pointer Number 1 Value: %d \n\n", *p);

    printf("Enter Number 2's Address to view it's value: ");
    scanf("%p", &p);

    printf("\nPointer Value: %d\n\n", *p);

    return 0;
}
```

`%p` is the correct format specifier to view addresses.

But even then if you look at the output, there can be a difference between address of Number 1 and p. Address of p has single `0x` while address of Number 1 has two `0x0x`. So, while entering address of Number 2, don't enter the extra `0x`.